# Setter method in constructor

Tags: java, methods, constructor, setter

Got a question that I come across

```
public class Student{
     private String studentNumber;
     private String studentName;
     private double studentResult;

     public Student (String aNumber, String aName){
         setStudentNumber(aNumber);
         setStudentName(aName);
         setStudentResult(0);
     }
     // The standard getter and setter method are define here.
}
```

what is the purpose of having the setter method in the constructor? and with the setStudentResult(0), do we need to have another instance variable?

Comment: Why would you need another instance variable? It looks like you have three setters and three instance variables... although the fact that a *number* is stored in a string is a bit worrying.

Comment: @Jon Skeet - A student number is probably not in fact a number.  Like a phone number isn't.

Comment: @DonRoby: Phone number isn't... but a student number probably should be, in my experience. Or it should be called a student ID.

Comment: Well, yes - student ID would be better.

Answer (score 5):

Calling overridable methods is an anti-pattern, it may cause problems if Student is overridden. A good pattern would be to make Student immutable

```
public class Student{
    private final String studentNumber;
    ...
    public Student (String studentNumber, ...) {
       this.studentNumber = studentNumber;
    ...
```

Answer (score 3):

The usual purported reason for setters in a constructor is so that you are using the same validation. However, self-encapsulation is an anti-pattern.

A much better for doing exactly what you have written is to have a static method which constructs the object and calls the set methods. Much better than that would be to make the whole thing immutable.

Answer (score 1):

You will have to use above code practice when you are dealing with validation of `sent`(which you are sending) value.
For example, if you don't want to allow any negative number to be set as a `studentNUmber` from the constructor then you have to write a logic to check the number either inside constructor or inside method depending on whether the class is immutable or mutable. If class is mutable then write logic inside method and if the class is immutable then write logic inside constructor(in immutable class writing setter method is not allowed because setter method can change the state of the object).
If you don't apply such logic then any negative value can be set to `studentNumber`.

Also, setter methods are useful when you have an object created in some other class and later you want to change it's state, say, you want to update the name of student, like given example below,

```
public class Student {
    private String studentNumber;
    private String studentName;
    private double studentResult;
    // The standard getter and setter method are define here.

    public Student(String aNumber, String aName) {
        studentNumber = aNumber;
        studentName =aName;
    }

    public String getStudentNumber() {
        return studentNumber;
    }

    public void setStudentNumber(String studentNumber) {
        this.studentNumber = studentNumber;
    }

    public String getStudentName() {
        return studentName;
    }

    public void setStudentName(String studentName) {
        this.studentName = studentName;
    }

    public double getStudentResult() {
        return studentResult;
    }

    public void setStudentResult(double studentResult) {
        this.studentResult = studentResult;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "studentNumber:"+studentNumber+", studentName"+studentName+", studentResult"+studentResult;
    }

}

class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Student s = new Student("1", "AAA");
        s.setStudentName("BBB"); //we should call this method because of "studentName" is private variable in Student class.
        System.out.println(s);
    }
}
```

about `setStudentResult`, you need not to have yet another instance variable as it is already declared in the `Student` class. Instead you need add one more parameter in the constructor to `setStudentResult` value.

```
public Student(String aNumber, String aName, long result) {
        studentNumber = aNumber;
        studentName =aName; 
        studentResult =result;
    }
```

Comment: I think it will cause problems when `Student` class is subclassed by another class, since subclass constructor always call super class constructor.

Comment: Just stating that something isn't a good practice isn't helpful at all. I disagree with your conclusion, but without any explanation it's hard to say exactly where.

Answer (score 1):

Are you doing any business logic in your setter methods. If yes i guess that's the reason you call setter from constructor. If you are just seeting your instance variable inside your setter, then setting the instance variable directly is the normal thing to do.

```
public class Student{
private String studentNumber;
private String studentName;
private double studentResult;

public Student (String aNumber, String aName){
this.studentNumber = aNUmber;
this.studentName=aName;
this.studentResult=0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Its not a good idea to call a method from an constructor.
Constructors are used to set the initial value of fields.

If you want to call methods from constructors and you dont want some one to override it. The declare the class as final

Comment: If the class is mutable, I think it's reasonable to call the setters from the constructor - that way, if there's any validation (e.g. the number can't be negative) you only have that logic in one place. I agree that it's a bad idea to call non-final methods from constructors, but the setters themselves could easily be made final.

Answer (score 0):

As previously mentioned using setter methods in a constructor is not a good idea for two reasons:

1. subclasses can override them, which would probably put the object in a state that wasn't taken into account.
2. a setter method can have functionality that you usually might not want in a constructor.

The reason why this is done is twofolds:

1. most often, the IDE (such as eclipse) does this automatically if you generate setter/getters after you write the constructor.
2. There are times when the setter method performs validations or formatting that you want to do when initializing with a constructor as well. In this case, I would suggest extracting the validation/formatting to a different function, and calling that function from both the constructor and the setter.